# Can I use knowledge from 8086 chips tutorial, with this Intel 82340SX?

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev

I have recently found old (very old) laptop and though that it might be great opporunity to learn assembly and some basic OS development.

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/b4zy4l.jpg]

Assembly tutorials are most often dedicated to the 8086 chips, so there my question is, does this Intel 82340SX make any difference? Does anything change regarding language usage?

Comment: Why not learn assembly and OS development on a newer machine?  That chip is a 386 relative, so yes some of your 8086 information will apply, but there will certainly be gotchas.

Comment: Well, my newest one's motherboard does not support floppy discs anymore, emulator testing just isn't 'it' and I do not want to risk damaging my pc. :)

Comment: 82340SX sounds more like a chipset than a processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 80386 chip is mostly (but not completely) backward compatible with 8086. For the differences, see the relevant section of Intel's 80386 Programmer's Guide (e.g. http://www.scs.stanford.edu/nyu/04fa/lab/i386/s14_07.htm ).

The 80386 also has new features that 8086 didn't support. A few important features are protected mode, paging and support for 32-bit code. I strongly recommend researching these features; as without them your software will be limited to slightly more than 640 KiB of RAM (the extra 3 MiB of RAM reported as "extended memory" will be wasted) and there will be no effective isolation between pieces of software (e.g. applications can trash each other and read each other's data). If you do this right, software designed for "80386 only" will be able to use about 3 GiB of RAM on new machines without any major changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try googling it? After a quick search I found out that it is a chipset IC for the 386SX.

see here - http://www.datasheetarchive.com/82340SX*-datasheet.html

So, you probably can't use 8086 knowledge to program that specific chip, although since your bootup screen is showing that then you can assume that your laptop has a 386SX CPU, which is backwards compatible with the 8086 CPU.

Comment: i80386 is backward compatible with i8086.

Comment: i know. i was just stating that the chipset being asked about isn't a cpu. I probably should have been explicit about that :)

Comment: I've never seen it referred to as i80386. I always knew it as 80386 or i386. My 2nd PC was a 386SX @ 20 Mhz. FEEL THE POWER! My phone has more processing power!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an 80386 PC, so all 8086 knowledge and code can be applied and reused on it.